# Android promo code

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to deliver some promo codes to some users but I just realized that Android Market doesn't have this feature, like shown

here: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/appy-talk-all-about-apps/2m8zvqr_HTo

and here: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/feature-requests--suggestions/3Spa5KuMgF4

Some people named the website http://www.twirkz.com/ as a workaround to deliver promo codes. My question is: is it reliable? I know that people who install from there will not receive any of the updates that comes from the Android Market, but is there some problem other than that?

If any of you would know an alternative way to give some free apps from my paid app, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play has now native support for promo codes.
From [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html):

> 1. Choose your app in the Developer Console.
> 2. Under the Promotions tab choose Add new promotion.
> 3. Review and accept the additional terms of service if you haven’t run a promotion before.
> 4. Choose from the options available, then generate and download your promo codes.
> 5. Distribute your promo codes via your marketing channels such as social networks, in email, on the web, to your app’s beta testers, or
>      in your app or game itself.
> 6. Users can redeem your promo codes in a number of ways, including: a) From Google Play, using the Redeem menu option. b) From your app.
>      They’ll be directed to the Play checkout flow before being redirected
>      back to your app. c) By following a link that embeds the promo code

Comment: Note that promo codes may break your remote server verification of purchases: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200722

Answer (score 6):

Simple method:

Looking over the app market, it seems to be a favourite of many a developer to release the free app, and sell a micro application that just unlocks extra features.
Could be advantageous, as people will download free apps before buying, and like this, they don't lose their data (or so they usually hope).
You could offer the unlocking application rather than promo codes at that point in time. Probably easier to manage, and unlikely the app will need many updates later on.
Also, don't forget that it's pretty much a given that you'll include ads in the free app, so I believe most users of the free app won't mind you making a little amount of money on the side.

Another simple method:

Promo codes in-app, again using the system as-above. Offer the free app, then sell the upgrade, but this time via a purchasable code. Then you could generate promo codes yourself.

Annoying method:

Refunds.
Seems to be employed by some developers. Requires manually refunding the user, but then they can receive app updates normally either way.

Hope that helps, even a little bit.

Comment: About the refunds, even if I choose this option, Google will still keep the transaction fees. Good answer, but unfortunately it doesn't apply to my case =/. +1

Comment: Yeah, they're a bit tricky like that. I guess it is their right to retain the cost amount for the transaction, but should still make it easier for someone like yourself in this situation. Thanks for the +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

According to Google, if you refund an item you should get the full transaction fee back.

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138001

Comment: Hum... I see. But the problem persists, because I will get the transaction fee back, not the user. So the user will still have paid for the app, which is not much of a promo =(

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is not directly from Google will have a chance at failing. I know that you can offer a discount and then put the price up again, but make sure you don't make it free. I don't believe you can go from "Free" to charging.